# is there an option that derive class can be inherited to base class in c++ OOP?

Tags: c++, class, oop

i have a point class which is inherited from the rectangle class(it is the assignment)
can the rectangle class be inherited from the point class?

```
1.class Rectangle: public Point
2.class Point: public Rectangle
```

Comment: Is this a homework? Did you try to compile it? Did you think about it, what it means and how an object could look like then?

Comment: this looks like a textbook [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). No there is not way to do that because it makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: U can't define two classes having the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Inheritance cannot by cyclic.

From object oriented design point of view, if all instances of class `A` are instances of the class `B` (in the object oriented sence), and if all instances of class `B` are instances of class `A`, then `A` and `B` should not be distinct classes - i.e. they should be the same class.